Matrix product state simulator gives incorrect result for more than 64 qubits
I am running the example to create the EPR circuit on a matrix product state simualtor from the qiskit documentation. The program does not work correctly if the number of qubits is more than 65. Here is the code.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

num_qubits = 65

simulator = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state', n_qubits=num_qubits)

circ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits, num_qubits)

# Create EPR state
circ.h(0)
for i in range (0, num_qubits-1):
    circ.cx(i, i+1)
circ.measure(range(num_qubits), range(num_qubits))

tcirc = transpile(circ, simulator)
result = simulator.run(tcirc).result()
print(f"Counts {result.get_counts()}")

I am getting the following result
Counts {'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000': 501, '01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111': 523}

Notice that the second dictionary key begins with a 0 which isn't correct since this is the EPR state. On the other hand if the number of qubits is less than or equal to 64, I get correct result.
Counts {'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111': 508, '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000': 516}

The only difference in the programs for up to 64 and more than 64 qubits is that in the latter, I also need to explicitly set n_qubits=num_qubits in the call to create the AerSimulator. Otherwise the transpilation failed with the following message.
'Number of qubits (65) in circuit-164 is greater than maximum (63) in the coupling_map'


The code works fine with Qiskit Aer version 0.13.3. I think it is a bug in version 0.14.0.

@Egretta.Thula 0.13.3 is taking a lot longer for my other circuit which was running much faster with 0.14. Also, for a larger number of qubits, the call to job.result().get_counts() is failing with 'Insufficient memory error'. job.result().get_counts() should return a dictionary with only num_qubit number of keys.
